# Where do I report packaging bugs? For example regarding dependencies

Tags: package-management, bug-reporting

Where do I report packaging bugs?

For example, 
If a package has a package has a 'dependency', which should actually be a 'recommends'.
Or a package should accept a meta-package, but calls for a specific package instead.

Should I locate the package on launchpad, and file a bug?
Or go upstream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same place you report other bugs: [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu)

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)